# How to list the DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) processed in a period of time when a general log was recorded?

Tags: mysql, ddl

How to list the DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) processed in a period of time when a general log was recorded?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use pt-query-digest (a free command-line tool, part of the Percona Toolkit) this way:

```
pt-query-digest --type genlog --no-report --output slowlog \
  --filter '$event->{fingerprint} =~ /^create|alter|drop/' \
  /usr/local/var/mysql/bkarwin.log
```

Output:

```
# Time: 2021-11-18T16:16:53.452721Z
# Thread_id: 24
# Query_time: 0.000000  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
create table foo (i int);
# Time: 2021-11-18T16:16:54.805065Z
# Thread_id: 24
# Query_time: 0.000000  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
drop table foo;
```

Those two statements are just test DDL statements I ran after enabling the general query log on my localhost MySQL instance.

The pt-query-digest tool also has options for restricting a date range, `--since` and `--until`. But I got an error when I tried it. It seemed to have a problem with the date format.

> Pipeline process 5 (since) caused an error: Argument "2021-11-18T16:16:53.452721Z" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at /usr/local/bin/pt-query-digest line 13660, <$fh> line 2.

Perhaps you can just skip the date range options and eyeball the output yourself.